# Weird behaviour with respond_with syntax for a Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

While building an api for Rails 3.0.3 app that serves json, some unexpected behaviour is happening.

Following is the controller. The question is about the `respond_with`. I already have `respond_to :json` in the app controller.

The create action just works and the data is also sent back after creation.

But the update action's `respond_with` doesn't send back any data.

The response body is blank.

```
def create
  line = get_line
  input_header = line.input_headers.create(params[:input_header])
  respond_with(input_header, :location => api_v1_line_input_header_url(line,input_header))
end

def show
 input_header = get_input_header
 respond_with(input_header.to_json)
end

def update
  input_header = get_input_header
  input_header.update_attributes(params[:input_header])

  respond_with(input_header, :location => api_v1_line_input_header_url(input_header.line,input_header))

  # render :json => input_header
end
```

When I use `render :json => input_header` instead of `respond_with`, it works.
Why is this?

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same error

Comment: Was this resolved? I know Rails was patched to return {} instead of " " but what if I want to return the whole object?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Rails 3.0.10 or even rails 3.1 to see if this is resolved? If it is, please answer and close the question.

Comment: Would you post the code for the entire controller class please.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `show` method is not too well, you do not need to call #to_json method, because `respond_with` is automatically calls the correspondent method when it detects the request needs json content or xml content.

Secondly, what happens exactly in `get_input_header` method? Can you replace it with standard rails `InputHeader.find(params[:id])` solution for one shot?

Answer (score 1):

respond_with returns body only for GET and POST requests, otherwise it returns only headers

look at [this RoR's code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb#L198)

```
 # This is the common behavior for formats associated with APIs, such as :xml and :json.
def api_behavior(error)
  raise error unless resourceful?

  if get?
    display resource
  elsif post?
    display resource, :status => :created, :location => api_location
  else
    head :no_content
  end
end
```

and the **josevalim**'s answer in [this pull request's discution (Make respond_with return JSON/XML for PUT requests)](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2643)

In my app I used monkeypatching for that :(

```
elsif put?
  display resource, status: :ok
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget append to controller respond_to?

```
respond_to :json, :html, ...
```

Comment: Nop, its already there. I didn't add that in the example above for clarity. Since, it works for the create action, I think its obvious.